# Rotate UIImageView, then Reverse Rotation when 'Tapped' (Animation)

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation

So, I've been working for hours trying to fix this, and I think It might just be missing something so obvious.

What Im trying to do is have an animation of a line (like a clock second hand) rotating around clockwise, but when the screen is pressed, it stops, but then when pressed again it starts again but the rotation reverses and the line starts rotating anticlockwise...

This is the code I used to rotate the line about a fixed point, and it works:

```
- (void) spinWithOptions: (UIViewAnimationOptions) options {
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.0f
                              delay: 0.0f
                            options: options
                         animations: ^{
                             Hand.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1);
                             Hand.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(Hand.transform, M_PI / 40);
                         }
                         completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                             if (finished) {
                                 if (animating) {
                                     // if flag still set, keep spinning with constant speed
                                     [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                                 } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) {
                                     // one last spin, with deceleration
                                     //[self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];
                                 }
                             }
                         }];
    }

- (void) startSpin {
    if (!animating) {
        animating = YES;
        [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];
        Clockwise = NO;
    }
}

- (void) spinWithOptions_Anti: (UIViewAnimationOptions) options {
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.0f
                              delay: 0.0f
                            options: options
                         animations: ^{
                             Hand.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1);
                             Hand.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(Hand.transform, -M_PI / 40);
                         }
                         completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                             if (finished) {
                                 if (animating) {
                                     // if flag still set, keep spinning with constant speed
                                     [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                                 } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) {
                                     // one last spin, with deceleration
                                     //[self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];
                                 }
                             }
                         }];
}

- (void) startSpin_Anti {
    if (!animating) {
        animating = YES;
        [self spinWithOptions_Anti: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];
        Clockwise = YES;
    }
}

- (void) stopSpin {
    animating = NO;
}
```

So at the start of the application, the line begins rotating clockwise, when the **ViewDidload** calls `startSpin`, which calls `spinWithOptions`...

Sure enough, if I press the screen, the rotation animation stops, with this...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{
    NSLog(@"Dircetion: %i", Clockwise);

    if(animating){
        [self stopSpin];
    }
    else{
        if(Clockwise){
            [self startSpin];
            NSLog(@"must be clockwise");
        }
        else{
            [self startSpin_Anti];
            NSLog(@"anti");
        }
    }
}
```

But when pressed again it starts rotating as It should but never changes direction... it only ever rotates clockwise...

I just can't seem to see why it won't change direction... even the NSLogs say the bool of Clockwise is correct...

Comment: When you call `spinWithOptions_Anti` try to removeAllAnimations from your Hand object before adding a new animation.

Comment: How do you remove all animations?

Comment: There is a method like this: `[Hand.layer removeAllAnimations];`

Comment: It's still not working :(

Comment: Yeah, I actually think you will want to removeAllAnimations at another spot, probably in `stopSpin`.  Are you sure that the reverse code works and spins it in the right direction?

Comment: I'll try. Yeh, the code works, because it just continues with the direction you set it to first, so if I start with an anti/counter clockwise, it continues that way...

Comment: Is there an feasible why I could consolidate the two methods and based on a BOOL, animate a specific direction?

Comment: For sure, thats what you are already doing but just with the animations in two separate methods.  I think your problem is that you aren't removing the animations and when you try to animate again, it performs the first animation that you put on the object.  If you remove the animation when you stop animating, then adding a new animation should work the way you are wanting.

Comment: I'd placed it in several places with no luck. Including `(void) stopSpin`, `animations: ^{...}` block and at the start of both `spinWithOptions` methods :(